# How to subclass within a complicated hierarchy?

Tags: python, class

If anyone can give me a better way to phrase my question in the title, I'll change it.

I'm using a library<sup>1</sup> and from that library I import some high level class:

```py
from library import HighLevelClass
```

In the library, `HighLevelClass` has an attribute which is an instance of another class, and that in turn has an attribute which is an instance of yet another class, and so on...

```py
class Bar():
    self.foobar = FooBar()

class Foo():
    self.bar = Bar()

class HighLevelClass:
    self.foo = Foo()
```

Now, I want to be able to replace some method of `Foo` for instance. I can't just do:

```
class MyFoo(Foo):
    def foo_method(self):
```

because `HighLevelClass` will still be referencing the `Foo` in the library, not my `Foo`.

I could try to unravel the hierarchy and subclass the `HighLevelClass` and make my way down to `Foo` subclassing everything as I go, but that's just madness.

What's the correct way to do what I'm trying to achieve?

**Footnotes**

<sup>1</sup> It doesn't really matter for the purposes of the question but here it is: [facebookresearch/detectron2](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2)

Comment: I don't know that there is a "correct" way. Class hierarchies are only as extensible as they are designed to be. Just because you want to modify `Foo` doesn't mean `HighLevelClass` is designed in a way to take advantage of your modifications. It *might* be as simple as setting `library.Foo = MyFoo` before creating an instance of `HighLevelClass`, though.

Comment: If the designers of `HighLevelClass` wanted it to be extensible, they might, for example, have a `foo_factory` argument to `HighLevelClass.__init__` that defaults to `Foo`, rather than hardcoding `Foo` in the definition. Then you could simply write `hlc = HighLevelClass(foo_factory=MyFoo)` instead of patching the class itself.

Comment: @chepner the library in question is actually [telling me to subclass Foo](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/6d250603acdbb69c8ef9cd7406ba8893c1e6d815/detectron2/modeling/roi_heads/roi_heads.py#L528). I presumed this was just one of those things I don't know how to do in Python yet. The class I'm actually instantiating in my code is called `DefaultTrainer`, and I don't even want to get started trying to follow the breadcrumbs that lead the latter to the former.

Comment: As for setting library.Foo, I didn't know that was possible. The library has a from `file import Foo; class HighLevelClass` somewhere in it. Can I really then just change what the definition of that `Foo` is?

Comment: @chepner on your last note, I'll look for that factory. This might be the day I learn what a factory is

Comment: Yes. Although the *value* of `library.Foo` comes from another file, `HighLevelClass` uses the *name* `Foo`, not `file.Foo`, to access it.

Comment: @chepner I see, so I would literally write a `class SubFoo(Foo)` then set `library.Foo = SubFoo`?

Comment: Correct. That *might* solve your problem, but it's a step forward.

Comment: @chepner okay, I hope my implementation was correct. But it did not work.

Comment: @chepner now I see what you mean when you say that the library is supposed to give me a mechanism. In fact, the library that I'm using uses a mechanism called a Registry.